# Trying to upload images via CSV and getting an error

Tags: magento-2.1, import, product-images

I'm trying to upload **1800 products** using **Magento import**. I'm not running into any issues aside from the images. When I try to upload them I get an error:

> Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to >timeout or access permissions in row(s)

I searched this error and found it asked before but only in regards to images imported internally from media/import and not from external links. I've narrowed down the issue to images coming from an https URL rather than http. When I import an image using http it doesn't seem to have the same problem. The issue I face is that these images are coming from our ERP system and thus are only available using https.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> **Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to >timeout or access permissions in row(s)**

**This error is thrown when the image is not found in pub/media/import folder.**

Magento Import might have given you the row number on which the image is incorrect. Check the next row of row number noted, search the image in pub/media/import folder.